Two netlink sockets receive packets in confusion
I initialized two netlink sockets of the same protocol family(ROUTE) in a function. However, the packet that should be sent to the second socket is always received by the first socket (the port number in the header is inconsistent). Why does this happen? What kind of thing? How to solve it?

Do not describe your code. Instead, add it to the question post (in form of [mcve]).
